# Twisted and writing exceptions to stderr

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, twisted, stderr

I am trying to use Twisted and Python together. I need to export exceptions and errors to a file rather than the console incase anything unexpected pops up during runtime and I happen to miss it, however redirecting stderr doesn't seem to work. The error still shows up in the console and it doesn't write to the file (although the file is created).

Here is a minimal example:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
import sys

sys.stderr = open('error.log', 'a')

def error_test():
    int("Hello")

reactor.callLater(1, error_test)

reactor.run()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sure it's not being written to file? I tried running your code and it works fine. Keep in mind, that Python keeps a lock on file while it's running, so it saves and closes it after being terminated.

Comment: I tried deleting the file, having the program creating a new one, so I know it's fresh and not locked. Still nothing is written to it. I am using Windows 10 version 1909, Python 3.6, and latest Twisted. (Probably should have mentioned)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `twist` (or `twistd`) to configure logging.  For example:

```
$ twist --log-file /tmp/some-file --log-format=text --log-level info web
^C
$ cat /tmp/some-file 
2020-10-18T10:35:41-0400 [-] Site starting on 8080
2020-10-18T10:35:41-0400 [twisted.web.server.Site#info] Starting factory <twisted.web.server.Site instance at 0x7fe59bbf4d70>
2020-10-18T10:35:41-0400 [twisted.application.runner._runner.Runner#info] Starting reactor...
2020-10-18T10:35:44-0400 [-] Received SIGINT, shutting down.
2020-10-18T10:35:44-0400 [-] (TCP Port 8080 Closed)
2020-10-18T10:35:44-0400 [twisted.web.server.Site#info] Stopping factory <twisted.web.server.Site instance at 0x7fe59bbf4d70>
2020-10-18T10:35:44-0400 [-] Main loop terminated.
$
```

This only requires structuring your application as a plugin that twist can find and launch.

More information on this approach is available at https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/tap.html (writing a plugin for `twistd` is identical to writing it for `twist`).

You could also configure the log system programmatically.  For example:

```
import sys

from twisted.logger import globalLogBeginner
from twisted.logger import textFileLogObserver

globalLogBeginner.beginLoggingTo([textFileLogObserver(sys.stderr)])

from twisted.internet import reactor

def error_test():
    int("Hello")

reactor.callLater(1, error_test)

reactor.run()
```

which sends the log to stderr, as visible here:

```
$ python /tmp/demo.py 2>/tmp/demo-err
^C
$ cat /tmp/demo-err 
2020-10-18T10:43:15-0400 [-] Unhandled Error
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/tmp/demo.py", line 15, in <module>
            reactor.run()
          File "twisted/internet/base.py", line 1283, in run
            self.mainLoop()
          File "twisted/internet/base.py", line 1292, in mainLoop
            self.runUntilCurrent()
        --- <exception caught here> ---
          File "twisted/internet/base.py", line 913, in runUntilCurrent
            call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
          File "/tmp/demo.py", line 11, in error_test
            int("Hello")
        exceptions.ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Hello'

2020-10-18T10:43:17-0400 [-] Received SIGINT, shutting down.
2020-10-18T10:43:17-0400 [-] Main loop terminated.
```

You can learn more about twisted.logger at https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/logger.html